# PayPal API How do I upload tracking numbers

Tags: paypal

I can't find the answer in the PayPal Api Docs.

I have a PayPal TRANSACTIONID. 
I have a USPS tracking number.

Using PayPal API (PHP), which api call do I use to tell PayPal what the tracking number is for my transaction?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, there is no API to push tracking numbers into PayPal transactions.

If you happen to be working with eBay transactions you can push tracking numbers back to the eBay transaction using the [SetShipmentTrackingInfo](http://developer.ebay.com/devzone/merchant-data/CallRef/SetShipmentTrackingInfo.html) API, but you can't do it directly to PayPal.

Comment: really? still? I'm secretly glad if it's true (because I have a lot of other stuff to do today) but it's pretty pathetic especially when the resolution center tells me "We noticed you didn't include shipping information for this transaction." as if I am the incompetent one

Comment: Yes, I've been begging for access to shipment tracking details via the API and/or IPN for a very long time now.  Unfortunately, they simply haven't done it.

Comment: @AndrewAngell Still we don't have any API to push tracking numbers into PayPal transactions?

Comment: Is it possible that in 2018, paypal STILL lacks an API to send tracking data into paypal?

Comment: Unfortunately, yes.  That is indeed the case.